# How to retrieve Year from a complete date ( Type: Date) with Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

I have a date field of type Date. I want to take that value of the year. thank you for giving me help.
because I searched the internet but I did not find the solution.
thanks for your understanding.

this is the format of date that i use :
     $date = $form->get('date')->getData();
    $date->format('Y-m-d')
this is my repository:

```
  public function findEnglishByTags($date, $categorie, $tags) {
    $tags_values = $tags->getValues();
    array_walk($tags_values, function (&$item) {
        $item = $item->getId();
    });

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('english');
    $qb->where('english.date = :date')
            ->andWhere('english.Categorie IN (:categories)')
            ->leftjoin('english.tags', 't')
            ->andWhere('t.id IN (:tags)')
            ->setParameters(array('date' => $date, 'categories' => $categorie->getId(), 'tags' => $tags))
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

my controller:

```
  public function searchAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm('MDWEB\FrontBundle\Form\InEnglishFrontType');
    $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $date = $form->get('date')->getData();
    $categorie = $form->get('categorie')->getData();
    $tags = $form->get('tags')->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $listEnglishs = $em->getRepository('MDWEBInEnglishBundle:InEnglish')
        ->findEnglishBytags(new \DateTime($date->format('Y')), $categorie, $tags);

    return $this->render('MDWEBFrontBundle:InEnglish:list.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'listEnglishs' => $listEnglishs
    ));
}
```

i want to change date by Year knowing that i haven't a field named Year in my entity.

Comment: Hi - what happens when you do `$date->format('Y')`?

Comment: I applied it, I did not encounter any problems but it does not send me the result I want to display (I want to search the publications by year and not by a complete date (year, month and day))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the query you use in your repository. Since you have a Date field in your database and you want to check if this date belongs to a specific year, you have to do something like this:

```
$startDate = $date->format('Y-01-01');
$endDate = $date->format('Y-12-31');

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('english');
$qb->where('english.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
        ->andWhere('english.Categorie IN (:categories)')
        ->leftjoin('english.tags', 't')
        ->andWhere('t.id IN (:tags)')
        ->setParameters(array('startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate, 
              'categories' => $categorie->getId(), 'tags' => $tags))
;
```

In fact most SQLs have a native YEAR function but Doctrine hasn't implemented it. You could install [doctrine extensions](https://github.com/oroinc/doctrine-extensions) so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The `new \DateTime($date->format('Y'))` won't work because there is no such constructor of `\DateTime` class. The one that exists, looks like this:

```
public __construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )
```

I am a bit confused by you code, so please help me understand it:

- Your form has `date` field
- From the form input you get `\DateTime` object
- You extract the year of submitted date and then wrap the year into new `\DateTime` and pass it to your repository
- Repository uses that "date" to query against a column named "date".

So, is your "date" columns really of type "date"?